# Why should CASE statement be within select statement?

Tags: sql

Why should `CASE` statement be within `SELECT` statement?

Why doesn't the second query work? I mean, why should `CASE` statement be within `SELECT` statement ?

First query:

```
SELECT 
    report_code,
    year, month, day,
    wind_speed,
    CASE 
       WHEN wind_speed >= 40 THEN 'HIGH' 
       WHEN wind_speed >= 30 AND wind_speed < 40 THEN 'MODERATE' 
       ELSE 'LOW' 
    END AS wind_severity
FROM 
    station_data;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
    report_code,
    year, month, day,
    wind_speed,
FROM 
    station_data
CASE 
   WHEN wind_speed >= 40 THEN 'HIGH' 
   WHEN wind_speed >= 30 AND wind_speed < 40 THEN 'MODERATE' 
   ELSE 'LOW' 
END AS wind_severity;
```

Comment: `CASE` - at least in **SQL Server** - is not a statement - but an **expression** (like `a+b`) and as such it returns a single, atomic value. You can use `CASE` wherever you could use `a+b` - which is as a column in the `SELECT` clause, or anywhere else (`WHERE`, `ORDER BY` etc.) where a single atomic value is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to conditional(derived) column (all when conditions) instead of selecting column itself. As per SQL syntax all columns (as it is or derived)should be part of select syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Because Second code is wrong syntax CASE statement place after FROM

we use CASE statement to make condition in column for each row. So, CASE statement need to be part of SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Your second query didn't work because it's in wrong `SQL syntax`, and no RDBMS support that syntax.

`why should CASE statement be within SELECT statement` CASE statement don't need to be only in SELECT statement. It could be in `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, ... too

Imagine someone say `I marry school and go to Peninsula`, why don't people know that `I and Marry go to Peninsula school`?

You could either learn SQL to write a proper query, or try creating another query language that let your query work, with different logic and syntax of your own.